# Draw line between two divs with jQuery DOM line

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to draw a straight line between two divs and found **[jQuery DOM line](https://github.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-dom-line)**, which seems to be a much smaller, simpler approach than **[jsPlump](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com)**.

I want to integrate it into my code, but it does not work. Here is my very basic example:

```
var fromPoint = $('#first');
var toPoint = $('#second');
$.line(fromPoint, toPoint);
```

As the docs tell me to do. While the console does not show any errors, the line does show itself neither. Wheres my mistake?

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRvzYg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this working code : [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/4cnn4qep/)

Actually problem is $.line required object with x and y value as parameter and in above question it passes html element in $.line function. So it was not working. So I have corrected it.

```
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}

var fromPoint = getOffset($('#first')[0]);
var toPoint = getOffset($('#second')[0]);

var from = function () {},
to = new String('to');
from.y = fromPoint.top+10;
from.x = fromPoint.left+10;
to.y = toPoint.top+10; 
to.x = toPoint.left+10;

$.line(from, to);

console.log('All scripts runned');
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. So I do not need to input some DOM Element, but a already calculated position?

Comment: Ah, no I see it. Maybe you could add `fromPoint and toPoint are required objects with x and y numeric properties, relative to the top left of the page. options is an optional object, as listed below.` to your answer to make it clear for anyone else… thanks :)

Comment: @DavidThomas I have updated answer and mention that what was issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: Hi Bharatsing, do you any idea that if we draw a line inside an element from your above script code. I tried and found the location, but it will be scattered. if I used the same your code then some lines are accurate and some lines are very long (it calculate the top from the body and show wrong)